# object reference ist not défine of a instance c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, datagridview, object-reference

Hellow guys i am creating a desktop app for checking students,
after i linked my database(postgres)with project  and show my table when ever i try to delete something it shows me this error  and the ID_student and DELETE/UPDATE button change postions with the first colums  [image]this is the normal one

then after i click on the delete button [image]
but on my database the user was deleted and the same error apear on my inscription the students is added but i got this error 
i search for many solution and checked my variables and almost lost hope 
this is my table

```
 private new void Select()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql= @"select  etudiant.id_etudiant,etudiant.nom,etudiant.prenom,etudiant.age,etudiant.sexe,etudiant.num,class.nom_class
                        from etudiant
                        inner join class on etudiant.classess=class.id_class";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());



                conn.Close();
                bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = null;//resete
                bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch ( Exception ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and this is my delete

```
        {
            if (bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Delete")
            {


                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = @"Select   all from deleteEtudiant(:id_)  ";
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_", int.Parse(bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString()));
                    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Deleted");



                    }



                    conn.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("User deleted don't forget the bug yassine" + ex.Message);

                }
            }
            if (bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Update")
            {

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = @"Select * from updateETUDIANT(':id_,:ST_Firstname ,:ST_prenom ,:ST_Age,:ST_Sexe,:ST_num');
";
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_", int.Parse(bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID_etudiant"].Value.ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ST_Firstname", (bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Nom"].Value.ToString()));

                    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("UPDATED");

                        Select();


                    }



                    conn.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)

                {
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("User UPDATED"+ex.Message);
                    Select();

                }


            }
```

i am sorry for the long post and i hope u can tell me how to improve

edit: i have a little question is my query wrong here ?

```
 public void Ajouter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql = "insert into etudiant (Nom, prenom, sexe) " +
                     "values(@Nom, @prenom,  @sexe);";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nom", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prenom", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.ToString());//
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sexe", bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Num", bunifuMaterialTextbox6.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Classess", bunifuMaterialTextbox7.Text);
                 int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();






                if (result==1)
                {
                    conn.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("Etudinat ajouter");

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex.Message);
                conn.Close();

            }


        }
```

it give me the same error object reference like the delete one

Comment: First, remove the try-catch block in the delete code and see, what variable isn't set.

Comment: Which line causes the error - have you tried adding a breakpoint at the top of the try block in the delete?

Comment: Also do not bother us with what you do (we do not care) and screenshots (again, we do not care). The site rules ask for a MINIMAL example - so the code throwing the error + the EXACT error (yeah, copy/paste is actually working) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

My answer here will be, that your Select is wrong? :)

```
try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = @"Select   all from deleteEtudiant(:id_)  ";
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_", int.Parse(bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString()));
                    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Deleted");



                    }
```

Shouldnt it be "Select * from deleteEtudiant(:id_)"; ?

EDIT: Answer to the other question:

```
  conn.Open();
                sql = "insert into etudiant (Nom, prenom, sexe) " +
                     "values(@Nom, @prenom,  @sexe);";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nom", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prenom", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.ToString());//
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sexe", bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Num", bunifuMaterialTextbox6.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Classess", bunifuMaterialTextbox7.Text);
                 int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

You need to put '@' in your parameters. Like this:
Because you are saying that in values, that the parameters name is (@Nom, @prenom,  @sexe);";

```
cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenom", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexe", bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks you sir it work but it's still the same the  after i delete the post the row dosnt get deleted in the app in till i reopen it again

Comment: You need to update your gridview. 
You can call the Select method again, so it will update the whole Gridview from the database.
Or the Gridview class should have a method to delete the row your are trying to delete.

Comment: I have also updated my answer to the other question.

Comment: still the same error but it was added in the database

Comment: Maybe this site could help you.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the ExecuteScalar(), use ExecuteNonQuery() instead of it;

```
int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

replace it with :

```
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i have a question how can i change the "'                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
''' to string with parse?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text != string.empty ? bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text : DBNull.Value);
if the age textbox is empty, the age will be null value in the database

Comment: after all the things i did i have a bug i don't know when i delete it tells me deleted then the table disapear and the default table apear like the table in my postgres data base any toughs about it?